# Remove a Value from an array in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

my document looks like this

```
{
 "_id": "9e3f079f072cb3e03d146774fd003238",
 "_rev": "1-ebf2242794ad0e4fa70ca263db4a3aad",
 "user_id": [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7
 ]
}
```

I just want to remove 7 from user_id array. Can I achieve in couchDb? I want result like

```
{
 "_id": "9e3f079f072cb3e03d146774fd003238",
 "_rev": "1-ebf2242794ad0e4fa70ca263db4a3aad",
 "user_id": [
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, what you're asking is if you can selectively remove an item inside an array. The only way to achieve this is to first fetch the whole document, then remove the item client-side, and push a new revision of the whole document, passing in the _rev of the document you read:

```
curl 'http://..../database/9e3f079f072cb3e03d146774fd003238'
{
  "_id": "9e3f079f072cb3e03d146774fd003238",
  "_rev": "1-ebf2242794ad0e4fa70ca263db4a3aad",
  "user_id": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}

curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -d  '{
            "_id": "9e3f079f072cb3e03d146774fd003238",
            "_rev": "1-ebf2242794ad0e4fa70ca263db4a3aad",
            "user_id": [1,2,3,4,5,6]
          }'

{
  "ok":true,
  "id":"9e3f079f072cb3e03d146774fd003238",
  "rev":"2-88d05ac5ef997d68d11dbafc8d07c933"
}
```

CouchDB as it currently stands does not allow for 'patching' existing documents, but require you to always provide the whole body when updating documents.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You just PUT the new version document, as [documented](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/document/common.html#put--db-docid).